# Change Application Title in .accde on startup

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access Front-End in which I want to auto-detect whether it is compiled into an accde, and then rename the apptitle.

```vb
If CurrentDb.Name Like "*.accde" Then
    CurrentDb.Properties("AppTitle").value = "Release Client"
    Application.RefreshTitleBar
Else
    CurrentDb.Properties("AppTitle").value = "Test Client"
    Application.RefreshTitleBar
End If
```

When I launch my .accdb in which I develop/test, everything works. I can change the apptitle manually, close and reopen, and it renames to Test Client. However, once I compile it, upon launching the newly compiled .accde, it does not rename the apptitle.

I tried moving the code from the AutoExec function to the first form's OnOpen event and even to the first form's OnTimer event (with a setting of 1).

If I run the code manually through the Immediate window, it resolves appropriately, so the code seems correct.

I think I'm missing the link between running this code in an .accdb and running it in an .accde.

Comment: I tested your code in Access 2010 from the form load event of my startup form.  It displayed *Release Client* as the app title of my ACCDE, and *Test Client* for the ACCDB.  I don't understand why it's not working for you.  :-(

Comment: Must you set app title again every time the database is opened?  Set it to *Test Client* in the ACCDB.  After you create the ACCD**E**, change it's app title to *Release Client*.  And after that would you ever need to change the ACCDE's app title again?

Comment: Oh, I certainly don't *have* to, but I was hoping I could so I never have to remember to keep renaming. :) As for the test, I'm currently working in Access 2016, so maybe that's the difference?

Comment: Well, I just realized I'm a fool. I was saving it out to one location, but had forgotten that I was using another location for my launcher to point to! Once I updated the proper location, it all worked properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was in the wrong, with the most basic of foolishness. I have a launcher which I was pointing to one location, but had forgotten to update my compilation to that new location. :)
Which means my original code works great, as HansUp mentioned, in the Form Load.